# Hibernate criteria Exception

Tags: hibernate

org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: agentbookingDet of: com.sutisoft.sutitravel.hibernate.AgentbookingDet

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your property "agentbookingDet" is misspelled or not mentioned in your mapping correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have public getter/setter of agentbookingDet in your AgentbookingDet class.